# Update not working for MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the entry in the database i have encrypted the field uniqueID

May be encrypted field uniqueId causing problem.

```
$query  = "SELECT UniqueID FROM configuration";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $dbuniqueID = Encryption::decrypt($row['UniqueID']);

    if($dbuniqueID == $UniqueID)    
    {
    //  $UniqueID = Encryption::encrypt($UniqueID);
        echo $UniqueID;
        $insert = "UPDATE configuration SET status = 'ready', original_conf_path = '$Filepath'
         WHERE UniqueID = '$UniqueID'";
         mysql_query($insert);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `$UniqueID` for your comparison or insert - it should be `$row['UniqueID']`

```
$insert = "UPDATE configuration SET status = 'ready', original_conf_path = '$Filepath'
             WHERE UniqueID = '$row[UniqueID]'";
```

You should also escape it:

```
    $insert = "UPDATE configuration SET status = 'ready',
        original_conf_path = '" . mysql_escape_string($Filepath) . "'
        WHERE UniqueID = '" . mysql_escape_string($row['UniqueID']) . "'";
```

Comment: now i have added one column in DB and Update is not working agian

Comment: $insert = "UPDATE configuration SET status = 'ready',
          original_conf_path = '" . mysql_escape_string($Filepath) . "'
          WHERE UniqueID = '" . mysql_escape_string($row['UniqueID']) . "'";
    mysql_query($insert);

Comment: i found where the issue is i am not able to inset the path 

properly C:\aksjdh\asd\asd

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert = "UPDATE configuration SET status = 'ready', SET original_conf_path = '".$Filepath."' WHERE UniqueID = '".$UniqueID."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is here: `WHERE UniqueID = '$UniqueID'";`

cause $UniqueID holds a decrypted value so UniqueID in database is different from that in variable.

But if $UniqueID holds encrypted value than this line won't work:  `if($dbuniqueID == $UniqueID`

cause you are comparing encrypted and decrypted values